# Access VBA nested for loop only works in first record

Tags: for-loop, ms-access, vba, do-while

I have an Access 2010 database, where one of the tables has a list of Beneficiaries, and Intermediaries.  For QC, I need to calculate the ownership of all Beneficiaries, and omit the ownership of entities that act as links between the bottom Beneficiaries and top Intermediaries.  So I have a table with 4 columns of intermediaries.  I want the following steps to occur:

1. start with column "IMY_Up1", select the first intermediary ID number
2. look through the second "IMY_Up2" column to see if that ID exists there.
3. If it does - edit the "Linked IMY" column to "Yes", if it does not exist in that column - edit the "Linked IMY" column to "No".

Issue I'm facing:  Current Code - Loops through accurately (Locals window shows 'i' and 'j' step through as expected).  But only the first row has it's "Linked_IMy" value updated to "No".

Attempted Fix:  put in 'Do While' loops.  But this causes loop to continue to run, and no 'i' or 'j' value is reached in the Locals window.

My ultimate question:  How can I change my code so it steps through and works as desired?  Do I need to re-design the whole thing, and if so, how should I start?

[image: snippet of table structure (fake data for proprietary reasons)]

Here is the VBA code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub modFieldlengthRegulate()

Dim i As Integer            'set "i" as integer for IMY_Up1 loop
Dim j As Integer            'set "j" as integer for IMY_Up2 loop
Dim db As DAO.Database          'imy database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'QC_LoopTestTable as recordset


Set db = CurrentDb                              'imy database
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("QC_LoopTestTable")   'QC_LoopTestTable as recordset

For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1                 'set up for IMY_Up1 loop

rs.MoveFirst                                    'always start at first row

'Do While Not rs.EOF

    'Set rs.Fields("IMY_Up1").Value = refSelect             'wanted to see what value it was assigning, but causes errors, so comment out

    For j = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1         'set up for IMY_Up2 loop
    rs.MoveFirst
        'Do While Not rs.EOF
        'Set rs.Fields("IMY_Up2").Value = compareSelect     'wanted to see what value it was assigning, but causes errors, so comment out
            If (rs.Fields("IMY_Up2").Value = rs.Fields("IMY_Up1").Value) Then
                rs.Edit
                rs.Fields("Linked_IMY") = "Yes"
                rs.Update

            Else:
                rs.Edit
                rs.Fields("Linked_IMY") = "No"
                rs.Update
            End If
        'Loop
    Next j

'Loop
Next i


rs.Close                    'close the recordset as part of the last step
Set rs = Nothing            'close the recordset as part of the last step
db.Close                    'close the database as part of the last step

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to do it with just SQL.  I can't see the image, so not sure

Comment: Also use `rs.MoveNext` to get it to move to the next record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the Power of SQL

A simple

```sql
SELECT QC_LoopTestTable.ID
    ,QC_LoopTestTable.IMY_Up1
    ,QC_LoopTestTable.IMY_Up2
    ,IIf(IsNull([QC_LoopTestTable_1].[id]), "No", "Yes") AS Linked_IMY
FROM QC_LoopTestTable
LEFT JOIN QC_LoopTestTable AS QC_LoopTestTable_1 
ON QC_LoopTestTable.IMY_Up2 = QC_LoopTestTable_1.IMY_Up1;
```

does the same much cleaner and faster (if IMY_Up1 and IMY_Up2 are indexed).

This fetches`QC_LoopTestTable`and joins with itself (`QC_LoopTestTable AS QC_LoopTestTable_1`) where Up2 = Up1.
If there is no match the result for the copied table (`QC_LoopTestTable_1`) is`NULL`what can be tested (Iif-Statement) and the corresponding value is (Yes/No) is used.

If you want to store the result of`Linked_IMY` you can use a similar`UPDATE`query, but this is not recommendet (usually don't store computed values), because if you edit a record, it needs to be updated again.

If`IMY_Up2`matches multiple`IMY_Up1`those values will be double but can be filterd if necessary

### Why your code fails

- Your code is updating only first row, because you don't tell the recordset to move to the next record.
- Then you would need two independent recordsets to loop one in the other (Inner loop with rs.MoveFirst would set outer loop rs to first row too (same variable`rs`))
- After you found a match, the inner loop needs to exit (`Exit Do`) or the next row will cause the revert as it will end in `Else`part writes to`Linked_IMY`.

Avoid`Integer`variables as they fail above 2^15-1, use`Long`instead.

Use`Do Until rs.eof ... Loop`to loop through recordsets.

Code could be like (just for demonstration, **don't use**):

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database        
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset         
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset  

Set db = CurrentDb                              
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("QC_LoopTestTable")   
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("QC_LoopTestTable") 

Do Until rs1.eof
  Do Until rs2.eof
    If rs1.Fields("IMY_Up2").Value = rs2.Fields("IMY_Up1").Value Then 

    ...

    End If
    rs2.MoveNext
  Loop
rs1.MoveNext
rs2.MoveFirst
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you @ComputerVersteher, I tried both these solutions and they both worked.  I did not know that you could make a copy of the table to query against (I already have a lot of tables in this DB and didn't want to split it - hence using VBA).

Comment: @CircularReference Don't use the VBA part, it is only for demonstration. Table is not a real copy, it is just used twice